# Regular Expression in PHP/Wordpress to validate Telephone Number

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

What will be the Regular Expression in PHP/Wordpress to validate Telephone Number So that Minimum Digit will be 10 and Maximum Digit will be 20 and it will not accept any dash (-)and special charters.  It will not take Zero as first digit.

Comment: Could you explain what you tried so far?

Comment: preg_match( '/^\d{10,20}$/', $tel );

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^[1-9]\d{9,19}$/
 │└─┬─┘└──┬───┘│
 │  │     │    └─ start of string
 │  │     └────── one digit > 0
 │  └──────────── min 9, max 19 digits
 └─────────────── end of string
```